# Magento 2 detecting a wrong version

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

My magento on readiness check detecting a wrong version 7.2.4   while on cli when I check its  7.1.2 . how I can solve this ?

Comment: Have you upgraded PHP version? If yes, there may be some PHP extension which has been installed for PHP 7.2.x.

Comment: Have you upgraded PHP version? If yes, there may be some PHP extension which has been installed for PHP 7.2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue.

And it is resolved by

- Removing  all magento cron from server.
- Deleting the file  .`setup_cronjob_status` from `var/`
  folder.**Magento read php version** from this file during **readline
  check**  and this file create using magento run.So, you need remove this file and it will generate again when cron is running again.
- After remove this file set , magento cron again at server.

It will resolve your issue